# Nope, Feedparser 5.2.1 isn't installing/working (for me) in Python

Tags: python, feedparser

Just trying to get feedparser 5.2.1 up and running. (On Windows 10/Python37 I'm kind of a noob at this, so I could be doing something stupid.)

I did a pip install AND a manual install. It looks like it installs fine, but it appears to be not working when I try to run anything. I've been installing and running plenty of other things (BeautifulSoup, etc) but his has kicked my ass.

This:

```
import feedparser
print(feedparser.__version__)
```

Gives me this:

```
AttributeError: module 'feedparser' has no attribute '__version__'
```

This:

```
myFeed = feedparser.parse('http://www.reddit.com/r/python/.rss')
print (myFeed['entries'])
```

Gives me this:

```
AttributeError: module 'feedparser' has no attribute 'parse'
```

My Python install is in the right place, right?

C:\Users\adead\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37

Where do I look next?

Comment: Did you happen to name one of your own files `feedparser.py`?

Comment: God damn it. :) C'mon..what else do you call your FIRST feedparser test file so it stands out from all the OTHER .py test files? Thanks! :P

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when installing `feedparser` for python 3.7 using '`pip install feedparser`' it installs an outdated `python 2.7` version. You either can revert to `python 3.6.8` or replace the erroneous `feedparser.py` file from 3.7 with the one of 3.6.8 at `./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/feedparser.py` (where virtualenv has the name `./venv/`) or when you do not have a virtual environment wherever the `feedparser.py` file is located.